# How to serve static file and give its path to one user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path, static-files

I am using jsmodeler (https://github.com/kovacsv/JSModeler) to show 3d models on my site. The only options for the user to select a file are through filepicker and through putting the path to the file in the url (ie http://localhost:3000/ModelView#https://cdn.rawgit.com/kovacsv/Online3DViewer/9e9ca71d/website/testfiles/cube.3ds). I would like to send a file through my node js server and then load the file into the viewer.

I think I need to put the path to the file that I am serving into the url and refresh the page? But how do I get this path?  It should only be available to one user so I cannot put it in the public folder!

Say I send it with

```
res.sendFile(myFile)
```

This does not send the path to the file right? I'm also worried that even if I get the path, when I refresh the page at the new url, the file will not be there anymore.

UPDATE:
So I am thinking when the model is saved on my server, I will save it in the public folder, but under a random number, ie "path/1982746/model.obj". That way no one can just type the model into the url. Is this safe, or can someone easily see all the files that are public?

Comment: Are you using Passport or any other authentication middleware? Do you want to serve the files to all logged-in users?

Comment: @Tom I am using Azure AD Authentication through tedious. I do not want to serve the file to all logged-in users, but I think that is the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the random number would help obfuscate the file from other users. You can upload the file to a node server using 'multipart/form-data' in the post request and save it in a location. Once saved, you can do something like

```
res.redirect('http://example.com/mypage/'+generatedNumber);
```

On the redirected page, you can form the appropriate path and load the file as it was any other file in your server directory.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was thinking I just wanted to double check. "help obfuscate", is there anyway to "totally obfuscate"?

Comment: Yes, you can hash your object name using md5. That way it could create a 32 character long alphanumeric hash. That'd let you hash 36^32 filenames with unique hashes without collision. 
If you'd want total security for the files, you can also serve the file dynamically from node server using filestreams. That way you can also check if the user is authorized to access  a particular file before serving it. Serving files this way has some performance overhead though. You can take a call depending on your use case.

Comment: You can use res.sendfile to send the files along with content-type header, which will abstract the underlying file-stream implementation for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a generic Url to download the files, just by sending the foler name you can download the file, in this way you can keep your file anywhere not necessarily at public folder.

```
app.all('/getModelFile', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('model.obj', {root: './public/pages/models/'+req.params.id});  // Params.id is 1982746 <- the folder name you can have mulitple model files inside the models folder send the folder name as id and fetch the file.
});
```

Hope this helps.